# Как происходит инициализация конструктора класса, наследуемого от ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, классы, asp.net-web-api, конструктор

Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, как происходит инициализация классов, которые реализуют *WEB API*. В частности, есть набор логики, у которых родитель - это `ApiController`, однако вопреки рекомендации, что такие классы должны содержать публичный конструктор без параметров, конструктор содержит некоторый список входных аргументов.

Например:

```
public class UserManagerController : ApiController {
...
public UserManagerController(IAccountManager accountManager, IUserContext userContext){
...
}
...
}
```

`AccountManager` и `IUserContext` - пользовательские интерфейсы. Мне больше даже интересен такой момент, как можно передать свой тип? К примеру, у интерфейса `IAccountManager` есть один реализующий класс, допустим создам еще один класс, реализующий данный интерфейс.

Как система определит, какой именно объект подставить в конструктор?

Comment: Почитайте как работает Dependency Injection

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection